# How to keep check boxes vertically aligned?

Tags: html, css

Right now I have a list of checkboxes inside a panel using:

```
            <div style="float:right; position:relative; ">
                <Label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box1</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b1)</Label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; position:relative; ">
                <Label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box2</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b2)</Label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; position:relative; ">
                <Label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box3</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b3)</Label>
            </div>
```

However, sometimes the checkboxes don't stay in their each individual lines and instead they jump onto the same line as another checkbox. E.g. I want it to be formatted into

Box1

Box2

Box3

But occasionally it becomes:

Box1
Box2

Box3

How can I fix this??

Comment: That means that they're occupying a combined width of more than 100% of the width of the container element. Check the width, or force then to use no more than `width: 33.33%` each.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do here is couple for solutions i have in mind

```
<body><div style="float:right;/* position:relative; */">
                <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box1</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b1)</label>
            </div>
  <br>
            <div style="float:right;/* position:relative; */">
                <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box2</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b2)</label>
            </div>
  <br>
            <div style="float:right;/* position:relative; */">
                <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box3</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b3)</label>
            </div>
</body>
```

Solution 2:

```
 <body><div style="/* float:right; */position: relative;">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box1</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b1)</label>
                </div>
                <div style="/* float:right; */position: relative;">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box2</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b2)</label>
                </div>
                <div style="/* float:right; */position: absolute;">
                    <label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box3</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem =&gt; item.b3)</label>
                </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you place all of your box's in a list as shown below to maintain an aligned vertical order i have also cleaned up your code a little bit to make it more readable

```
<ul style="float:right; position:relative; ">
  <li>
    <Label>
      <span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box1</span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b1)
    </Label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul style="float:right; position:relative; ">
  <li>
    <Label>
      <span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box2</span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b2)
    </Label>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul style="float:right; position:relative; ">
  <li>
    <Label>
      <span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box3</span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b3)
    </Label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

a demo can be found:[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0pu0dbhf/)

You can read more about html list's [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [clear your floats](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Apply this style to the parent element:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

In your case:

```
<span class="group">
    <div style="float:right; position:relative; ">
        <Label><span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:16px;">Box1</span> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.b1)</Label>
    </div>
<span>
```